# Client handler not recognizing my trusted API certificate

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ssl-certificate

I have a problem using HttpClientHandler, when I use a new instantiated API calls are considered unreliable, when using native this does not happen, does anyone know what may be happening? Or what must be done to make my handler behave properly?

Below are the code snippets where I instantiate and use it.

```
private static HttpClient ConfigureClient(string endpoint)
{
    return new HttpClient(_authenticatedHttpClientHandler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri($"{Endpoints.FULL_URL}/{endpoint}"),
        Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, ServiceConfiguration.TIMEOUT)
    };
}

public static void RegisterContainer(IContainerRegistry container)
{
     _authenticatedHttpClientHandler = new AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler();

    container.RegisterInstance(_authenticatedHttpClientHandler);
}
```

The certificate was created using the Let's Encrypt (wildcard) tutorial.

Stacktrace:

> {System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed,
>   see inner exception.) --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication
>   failed, see inner exception. --->
>   Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: CertificateUnknown at
>   Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.EvaluateTrust () [0x000bf] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:306
>   at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00075] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:213
>   at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake
>   (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean
>   renegotiate) [0x000da] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:840
>   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run
>   (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:289
>   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation
>   (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:223
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication
>   (System.Boolean runSynchronously,
>   Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0025c] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:406
>   at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream
>   (System.Net.WebConnectionTunnel tunnel,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00176] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsStream.cs:137
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.WebOperation
>   operation, System.Boolean reused, System.Threading.CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) [0x00170] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:222
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.WebOperation
>   operation, System.Boolean reused, System.Threading.CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) [0x00208] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:234 at System.Net.WebConnection.InitConnection (System.Net.WebOperation
>   operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x000f7] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:263 at System.Net.WebOperation.Run () [0x00052] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268
>   at System.Net.WebCompletionSource1[T].WaitForCompletion () [0x0008e]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebCompletionSource.cs:111
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T]
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32
>   timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted,
>   System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000e8] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:956
>   at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler.SendAsync
>   (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0029b] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/MonoWebRequestHandler.cs:485
>   }

Comment: Do you use a self-signed certificate? What value do you have in your .csproj file for the key `<MtouchTlsProvider>`? The two value options are `Default` and `Legacy` where `Default` is the Apple TLS provider and `Legacy` is the Mono TLS provider (TLS1.0 only)

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT 

<MtouchHttpClientHandler> NSUrlSessionHandler </MtouchHttpClientHandler> is a tag closest to what you said, that you commented on and has no value. I don't have the one you mentioned.

Comment: Can you share a demo that could re-produce this issus?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT To reproduce a problem, simply create an httpclienthandler and use the calls, of course, with a server that we will encrypt.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a problem using HttpClientHandler, when I use a new instantiated API calls are considered unreliable, when using native this does not happen, does anyone know what may be happening?

According to Managed section of [TLS of iOS and Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack#managed) Managed implementation of HttpClient:

> It is not fully integrated with the Apple OSes and is limited to TLS 1.0. It **may not be able to connect to secure web servers or cloud services in the future**.

And according to [Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/transport-layer-security?tabs=macos):

> **April, 2018** – Due to increased security requirements, including PCI compliance, **major cloud providers and web servers are expected to stop supporting TLS versions older than 1.2.** Xamarin projects created in previous versions of Visual Studio default to use older versions of TLS.

So the native implementation of HttpClient should always be used instead of managed way to support TLS1.2+.

Comment: I use native implementation, I only change the Handler because I need to manage headers for my calls, on some routes I need headers different from others ... Is it possible to do this without changing the handler?

Comment: Headers are set in the handlers programmatically, so I don't think it is possible to change the headers without changing the handlers. You can create different handlers with different headers for some routes.

Comment: yes, but this way you can attach a different handler, and that's what causes the problem.

Comment: You mean creating another handler for http request causes the exception? If so, that would be interesting. Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the issue? Feel free to replace any sensitive information with placeholders.

Comment: Exactly, in the first method in the code snippet of the question I instantiate a Client using an HttpClientHandler that I created myself. If I remove the parameter, everything works.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Did you ever find a solution for this? I think I'm just now encountering the same problem.